# Class HomeController does not exist, upgrading laravel 4.2 to 5.0

Tags: upgrade, laravel-5

I am upgrading laravel 4.2 to 5.0 using following document :

http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

I complete these points :  `Controllers`, `Route Filters`

than after 
following errors come's :

```
in Container.php line 776
    at ReflectionClass->__construct('HomeController') in Container.php line 776
    at Container->build('HomeController', array()) in Container.php line 656
    at Container->make('HomeController', array()) in Application.php line 572
    at Application->make('HomeController') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 83
    at ControllerDispatcher->makeController('HomeController') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'HomeController', 'showLogin') in Route.php line 198
    at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 131
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 689
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 690
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 660
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 160
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 111
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 150:
Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

Comment: The error about `HtmlServiceProvider` is because the HtmlBuilder isn't included in the core anymore. You need to require `illuminate/html` in with composer

Answer (score 0):

Finish the upgrade. Later in the documentation, you can find this:

> Form & HTML Helpers
>
> If you're using Form or HTML helpers, you will see an error stating
>   class 'Form' not found or class 'Html' not found. To fix this, add
>   "illuminate/html": "~5.0" to your composer.json file's require
>   section.
>
> You'll also need to add the Form and HTML facades and service
>   provider. Edit config/app.php, and add this line to the 'providers'
>   array:
>
> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider', Next, add these lines to the
>   'aliases' array:
>
> 'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 'Html'      =>
>   'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',